# Cannot stop BASH when using of && and || operators

Tags: bash, ubuntu, exit

I would like to stop my BASH if the commands have any errors.

```
make clean || ( echo "ERROR!!" && echo "ERROR!!" >> log_file && exit 1 )
```

But seems like my BASH still keeps going. How do I put `exit 1` in the one-line operators

I am very new to BASH, any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`exit 1` exits from the subshell created by `()`, not the original shell. Use `{}` to keep the command group in the same shell.

Don't use `&&` between commands unless you want to stop as soon as one of them fails. Use `;` to separate commands on the same line.

```
make clean || { echo "ERROR!!" ; echo "ERROR!!" >> log_file ; exit 1 ;}
```

Or just use `if` to make it easier to understand.

```
if ! make clean
then
    echo "ERROR!!"
    echo "ERROR!!" >> log_file
    exit
fi
```

Comment: I'd use `;` (or line breaks, as in the `if` version) instead of `&&` between the `echo`s and `exit` -- with `&&`, if either `echo` command fails for some bizarre reason, it won't run the `exit`... and if things are so messed up that `echo` can't run, you *really* want to exit the script.

Answer (score 2):

You have the direct solution in [Barmar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71757101/7582247). An alternative if you want to check multiple commands in a similar way could be to define a function which could be reused:

```sh
die() {
    echo "ERROR: $@"
    echo "ERROR: $@" >> log_file
    exit 1
}

make clean || die "I left it unclean"
make something || die "something went wrong"
```

or, if you want the script to end at first sign of trouble, you could use `set -e`

```sh
set -e

make clean     # stops here unless successful
make something # or here if this line fails etc.
```

You may want to log an error message too, so you could install a `trap` on `ERR`. `errfunc` would here be called before exiting the script and the line number where it failed would be logged:

```sh
errfunc() {
    echo "ERROR on line $1"
    echo "ERROR on line $1" >> log_file
}

trap 'errfunc $LINENO' ERR
set -e

make clean
make something
```